# Deploy application in IBM Cloud using only Rest API

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, rest-assured

I am an intern and currently doing automation on a software. What I need to do is to automate the process of creating, and starting an application in the cloud foundry using Rest API (rest-assured). I can't start an app because to start it I need to upload bits. I searched for weeks and still cannot find how to do it. I can only use V2 of the Cloud Foundry API, because when I create an app using the V3 API it doesn't show in the dashboard. I don't know why so we decided to just leave it and use V2 instead.

**My question is:** Is there any way to create, and deploy/start an app using only Rest API with the V2 API of the Cloud Foundry API? If there is a way to do this by using V3 API, I'm willing to search for the solution to solve the issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you use V3 API? Any errors?

Comment: http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.50.0/index.html . No errors, but the dashboard did not show any application that was created by this. I don't know why.

Comment: add your exact API call to the question above, what and how did you use the API, which parameters, ...

Comment: If you run `cf -v push`, it should print the HTTP requests being made. You can use that as an example of what needs to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by combining V3 API with V2 API. I understand the upload bits in V3 API. I use link[1] mainly to start the app. I think you can't create a route in V3 API because I don't see any endpoint for that, so I use V2 API instead to create and assign. I also use V2 API to create my app because of what I stated in my question. Thanks for answering the question because without the answers given by good people here I can find the best way to solve this.

[1] Create an App using V3 : https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng/wiki/How-to-Create-an-App-Using-V3-of-the-CC-API
[2] V2 API doc : https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/3.1.0/routes/list_all_apps_for_the_route.html .
[3] V3 API doc : http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/release-candidate/index.html#get-assigned-isolation-segment

Answer (score 0):

I think others commented on your question to use the `cf` command line, but if you want to use whats behind the scenes of `cf` then you can refer to the [REST API Docs](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/2.9.0/). At the top the page there is a API version selector (I linked 2.9.0 since you mentioned V2).

More specifically, to create an app you can use the [Create App Endpoint](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/2.9.0/apps/creating_an_app.html); then to upload the bits, you can use [Upload Bits Endpoint](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/2.9.0/apps/uploads_the_bits_for_an_app.html).

I hope this helps. Definitely check out the main docs, there are *tons* of endpoints that might be useful. Good luck on your internship!

EDIT: Just in case you need the CF API URL its https://api.ng.bluemix.net

Comment: I did use that, but the thing is how to translate the body in the upload bits? I don't understand at all. The body is different from other endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how the cli uses the rest api behind the scenes you can temporarily set the environment variable `BLUEMIX_TRACE` with the command line  `EXPORT BLUEMIX_TRACE=TRUE`.

Then you can try doing `cf push` or `cf start`, `cf stop`, etc, and you will see the http requests the CLI uses. This has helped me a lot versus digging through the CF documentation :). Hope it helps!